# Assigning two separate colours for a list of nodes in a graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I would like to show a graph which contains two different colors for each set of nodes that I have.

I have tried to define a function to assign each node color to a node in a list, however python does not seem to recognize one of my lists and so ends up printing all of my nodes in the same color. I feel like I am missing something very basic but I just can't see it.

Edit: Nodelist1 is essentailly a sequence of nodes that represent a pathway between two nodes. All of the numbers in Nodelist1 are in Graph.nodes()

```
Nodelist1=[1,2,7,9,13] 
def nodecolor():
    for n in Graph.nodes():
        if n in list(NodeList1):
            node_color='red'
        else:
            node_color='blue'
    return node_color

nx.draw_networkx(Graph, node_color=nodecolor(), edge_color='red' )
```

Ideally this should draw a graph which shows two different colors. However it only shows the color blue.

Comment: Can you include the definition of, or assignment to `NodeList1` as well?

Comment: @ilim I've edited the question, hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be assigning a single string to `node_color` variable, as opposed to a list, for instance. Since `nodecolor()` function returns a single string, `draw_networkx` receives a single color to draw the graph with.

If you view the documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html), you can see that you can feed a sequence of strings to `node_color` parameter of `draw_networkx`, though length of the sequence should be equal to the list of nodes.

Although I am not experienced in the particular library you are using, I believe a simple modification of your function `nodecolor()` as given below would work.

```
def nodecolor():
    node_colors = []
    for n in Graph.nodes():
        if n in list(NodeList1):
            node_colors.append('red')
        else:
            node_colors.append('blue')
    return node_colors
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, I did indeed look at this before posting the question. I understood the part that the sequence of colors should be the same as the nodelist. The function I created was aimed to do this, however I am still a beginner at python so didn't really understand if what I was writing was what I wanted. Perhaps changing the function slightly to "for n in range(len(Graph.nodes()))". Would this work?

Comment: @ViB Have you tried the sample code I posted as part of my response?

Comment: Sorry when i first read your response I didn't even see your sample code. This  works exactly how I wanted it to! Thank you!